# Getting Nginx to serve more than one virtual server for node apps

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

So, I am having a really hard time right now. I have two nodejs applications. One is running on port 8080, and one on 8081. They are both running on the same ip addresses. I have two domains, domain1.com and domain2.com. I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy to redirect domain1.com to port 8080 and domain2.com to port 8081. My problem at the moment is that domain1.com is the only on that works. I can only access the other node app by going to domain1.com:8081 or domain2.com:8081.

My nginx file structure:
[image: nginx file structure]

domain1.com.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

domain2.com.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been racking my brain a this for so long, and I can not find many relevant answers online.
BTW, I a running all of this on CentOS 6.3

**UPDATE:** after troubleshooting some more. I discovered that my problem might not be an nginx problem because I completely shut the nginx service down and my node app was still displaying. It is weird because nothing is running on port 80. I even used the netstat command to check if anything was running on port 80. I am so confused right now. If anyone has any idea on how to fix this or how to troubleshoot further. Please let me know.

Comment: Why do you have both domains in `server_name`?

Comment: As Alexey said, you have a typo in domain2.conf. Use `server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com;` instead of `server_name domain1.com www.domain2.com;`

Comment: Was a typo on my part, was not like that in the actual config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an nginx expert but this kind of setup works for me:

```
upstream www.domain1.com {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.com,www.domain1.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://www.domain1.com;
    }
}

# same for domain2
```

Comment: Cool, I'll try this.

Comment: I'll add the closing bracket for the location block

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how or why this worked, but restarting my server seemed to solve this issue. I still haven't the slightest clue what was causing this, but the power flickered at my house, my server restarted, and everything worked fine with the configuration I had to start. Thanks to anyone who tried to help. I am marking ShanShan's answer as the correct one since his/her configuration is valid and works fine.

Comment: You have to [restart or reload nginx when the conf changes](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/714e96633c-reload-the-nginx-configuration).

Comment: I just thought you forgot to restart nginx :p

Comment: It's alright. I'm sure that happens more than it should. Not restarting something after you make changes.